# Tmux split window vertically and define top pane's height

Tags: terminal, nvidia, tmux

I have a small script which turns my terminal into a monitoring view for the GPU. The `nvidia-smi -l 1` command I run in one of the panes requires it to be a certain height though, which I can calculate based on the number of GPU processes using

```sh
smi_processes=$(nvidia-smi pmon -c 1 | wc -l)
smi_height=$((${smi_processes} + 3))
```

(Have not done proper calculations yet.)
I want this process to run in the top right pane though, but don't know how I can assign that pane a certain height. I can define the height of the bottom right pane just fine.
This is my current script:

```sh
smi_processes=$(nvidia-smi pmon -c 1 | wc -l)
smi_height=$((${smi_processes} + 3))
tmux \
    new-session  'htop' \; \
    split-window -h 'nvidia-smi -l 1' \; \
    split-window -v \; \
    split-window -v 'xdotool key F11'\; \
```

This will split the right two panes evenly and then set the terminal to full screen. I can define the bottom pane's height with `split-window -v -l [height] \; \` but this would mean the top window will have different heights on different size monitors, or different terminal settings.
I tried spawning the process in the bottom pane, sizing it and then swapping the pane up using `swap-pane -U`, but the size is linked to the bottom pane.
TL;DR:
How can I have the top right pane be a certain height, and the bottom right pane to take up the rest of the space?

Thanks in advance!

Current result:
[image: Current result]

Comment: Have you tried the `resize-pane -y` command?

Comment: @meuh I had played around with that command a lot already but finally managed to get it working just now

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by moving the fullscreen command and by using `resize-pane -y` and `select-pane`:

```sh
smi_processes=$(nvidia-smi pmon -c 1 | wc -l)
smi_height=$((${smi_processes} + 5))
tmux \
    new-session  'htop' \; \
    split-window -h 'nvidia-smi -l 1' \; \
    split-window -v \; \
    split-window -v 'xdotool key F11'\; \
    select-pane -t 1 \; \
    resize-pane -y $smi_height \; \
    select-pane -t 2 \; \
```